# How can I make the height equal on left and right hand side using only CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I needed to make the height of the Hero elements equal heights as can be seen here https://codepen.io/hellouniverse/pen/KqvYoj. I did it using JavaScript. However, I am feeling very yucky. I tried to make the height equal using CSS flex. However, I was unable to make the height using CSS only when the number of lines of text inside the white box is different on the left and right-hand side.

How can I make the heights equal using only CSS when the line numbers are different?

```
  var $firstHeroTwinHeight;
  var $secondHeroTwinHeight;
  var $firstHeroTwinHeightContents;
  var $secondHeroTwinHeightContents;

  if ($(window).width() > 767) {
    if ($('.section-hero').length > 0) {
      $firstHeroTwinHeightContents = $('.section-hero .field-items .field-item:first-child .hero__contents');
      $secondHeroTwinHeightContents = $('.section-hero .field-items .field-item:last-child .hero__contents');
      $firstHeroTwinHeight = $firstHeroTwinHeightContents.outerHeight();
      $secondHeroTwinHeight = $secondHeroTwinHeightContents.outerHeight();

      if ($firstHeroTwinHeight > $secondHeroTwinHeight) {
        $secondHeroTwinHeightContents.css('height', $firstHeroTwinHeight);
      }
      else {
        $firstHeroTwinHeightContents.css('height', $secondHeroTwinHeight);
      }
    }
  }
```

I have a codepen https://codepen.io/hellouniverse/pen/KqvYoj  where I tried to replicate what I am having without the js

Comment: Although I could make a best guess, it would be useful if you could share the relevant HTML code.

Comment: Actually, you are right. I should try to have some kind of codepen atleast.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess :)

```css
.field-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  /* justify-content: space-between; ** pushes children to the sides
  justify-content: flex-start; ** pushes children to the left
  justify-content: flex-end; ** pushes children to the left */
  padding: 1em;
  border: thin solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section-hero">
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/200/00ff00"></div>
      <div class="field-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/200/0000ff"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```